# d3's selection.text() is expensive

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, d3.js

I am following the [general update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) and I have a lot of `<text>` elements with dynamic content which means that every update call `selection.text()` gets called numerous times which especially in Microsoft Internet Explorer and Edge makes quite a difference:

[image: Timeline]

[image: Call stacks]

What would be a simple way to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [original code for `selection.text()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/selection/text.js) I created `selection.cachedText()`, a version which caches the text using data attributes. The attributes are accessed/assigned using `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` (`dataset` is unsupported for SVG content in IE and old Edge versions):

```js
function textRemove() {
  this.textContent = "";
}

function textConstant(value) {
  return function() {
      if (this.getAttribute("data-text") !== value) {
        this.textContent = value;
        this.setAttribute("data-text", value);
      }
  };
}

function textFunction(value) {
  return function() {
    var v = value.apply(this, arguments),;
        text = v == null ? "" : v;
    if (this.getAttribute("data-text") !== text) {
      this.textContent = text;
      this.setAttribute("data-text", text);
    }
  };
}

d3.selection.prototype.cachedText = function(value) {
  return arguments.length
      ? this.each(value == null
          ? textRemove : (typeof value === "function"
          ? textFunction
          : textConstant)(value))
      : this.node().textContent;
};
```

The performance is far from optimal, as mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#Issues:

> The main issues to consider are Internet Explorer support and performance. Internet Explorer 11+ provides support for the standard, but all earlier versions [do not support `dataset`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset). To support IE 10 and under you need to access data attributes with [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)  instead. Also, the [performance of reading data-attributes](http://jsperf.com/data-dataset) compared to storing this data in a JS data warehouse is poor.

So a solution using a JS data structure instead of the DOM would be better.